# How to set a functions parameter type to be a property KEY of ONE of a type's properties? Is this even possible?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How does one set a function's parameter type to accept a **key** of **one** of a type's properties? Is this even possible?

```ts
type A = {
    ['prop1']: string;
    ['props2']: boolean;
}
// arg would be either 'prop1' or 'prop2'
const example = (arg: property in A ) => {}
```

My assumption is that this is not even possible. If so, is there a way to get around this?

Is there a way to declare a type similar to how you can declare an object with an `enum`? Obviously, this is an object below, but could you do something similar with a type?

Example:

```ts
enum Enum {
    bold = 'bold',
    italic = 'italic',
}
const objWithEnumProperties: {[key in Enum]: any} = {
    [Enum.bold]: '',
    [Enum.italic]: ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to set a functions parameter type to be a property KEY of ONE of a types properties? Is this even possible?

Yes, using TypeScript [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```ts
type Foo = { bar: string; baz: boolean; }

// arg is 'bar' | 'baz'
const fn = (arg: keyof Foo) => {}
```

> Is there a way to declare a type similar to how you can declare a object with an enum?

You are probably wanting a [`const` object assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) or an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```ts
// Usable at runtime
const Foo = {
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: 'baz'
} as const;

// Only for typing
interface Foo {
  bar: string; 
  baz: boolean;
}
```